# XSLT - Adding an IF statement to check XML for colon

Tags: xml, if-statement, xslt

I am working on a project with XSLT and XML files.

I need to add logic to the XSLT to check if a colon has been entered into the FTYP_Location, and if it has I need everything BEFORE the colon removed (including the colon). Here is an example of the data that needs to be parsed:

```
 SAINT MARY FL:@TARGET
```

Below is the XSLT that I am currently using (the FTYP_LOCATION is the field that will be modified by the IF statement).

```
<xsl:template match="fieldEvent">
  <MobResMDT>
    <xsl:call-template name="header" />
    <request>
      <FieldEvent>
        <FTYP_TYCOD>
          <xsl:value-of select="type" />
        </FTYP_TYCOD>
        <FTYP_SUBTYCOD>
          <xsl:value-of select="subtype" />
        </FTYP_SUBTYCOD>
        <FTYP_LOCATION>
          <xsl:value-of select="location" />
        </FTYP_LOCATION>
        <FTYP_CMNTS>
          <xsl:value-of select="comments" />
        </FTYP_CMNTS>
        <FTYP_PLATE swtype="swchar">
          <xsl:value-of select="plateNumber" />
        </FTYP_PLATE>
      </FieldEvent>
    </request>
  </MobResMDT>
</xsl:template>
```

The other thing that could be done, is instead of checking for a colon, we could remove everything before the "@" sign that will be in the code.

I have tried writing the necessary if statement, but have failed numerous times. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Cannot properly hammer down the IF statements (I'm used to working in object-oriented programming, not data fields like XML)

Comment: What version of xslt are you using?

Comment: It's always useful to say which version of XSLT you are using, since many things are much easier in 2.0+, but in some environments you're still constrained to 1.0. Further, if you've tried lots of things, it's useful to tell us in detail one thing that you tried, and to tell us how it failed -- that way we can often see where it is that you've "got the wrong end of the stick".

Comment: I am using version 1.0 sadly...

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the text you want starts with a `@`, you could do simply:

```
<FTYP_LOCATION>
    <xsl:text>@</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(location, '@')"/>
</FTYP_LOCATION>
```

Or, in XSLT 2.0:

```
<FTYP_LOCATION>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(location, '^.*(@)', '$1')"/>
</FTYP_LOCATION>
```